# How to implicitly append a column as a part of where clause in all select statements

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

We have a web application written with asp.net/c#  and uses sql server as SGBD in our database, in almost tables,  we have a column called 'YEAR', so in a lot of `select` statement we have

```
select * from table where ... and  Year = '2012'
```

for example

is there any way to refactor those queries in order to make  the 'and  Year = '2012'' part implicit?

Comment: What do you mean by "refactor"?

Comment: @anouar204 depends on the method or methods that you use to build your sql statements. Have a code example?

Comment: we dont want to add the 'and Year  = ...' in our queries all the time, so if you have any idea that can help, it well be great

Comment: @jordanhill123  the data access layer is written with pure ado.net, the probleme is that when we write new features we can forgot to add this omnipresent part of the query, that is why we are looking for a method to make it implicite 'automatic'

Comment: @jordanhill123 may be somthing like creating virtual instance for the database and for each instance we have a unique value for the Year column

Comment: @anouar204 do you have the option of stored procedures?

Comment: @anouar204 do you want the "implicit year" to be equal to the unique value from each instance of the database

Comment: @jordanhill123 the column Year is just an example, we can say that the problem is about column wich is present in all database tables; for example let say that we have a table in wich for 100 row we have Year = '2012' and for 200 row we have = '2011', my question is can we do a global projection for all the tables to filter only rows with Year = '2012' that way we dont have to put the and Year = '...' all the time we write a new query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass DateTime as a string. Use SQL Command and pass it as 
`DateTime.Now.Tear()`

Short Code Example:

```
void int SQLQueryWith Implicit Date() { 
    // Create a sql statement with a parameter (@ImplicitYear) 
    string sql = @"SELECT rank = Count(*) 
                   FROM   table 
                   WHERE  table.date >= @ImplicitYear"; 


// Create a sql connection 
// Always use the using statement for this 

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) { 

    // Create a sql command 
    // Always use the using statement for this 
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection)) { 

        // Pass the dateinput argument to the command, and let 
        // the .NET Framework handle the conversion properly! 
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlCommand("ImplicitYear", DateTime.Now.Year())); 

        // No need for calling .Close() or .Dispose() - the using 
        // statements handle that for us 
        return (int)command.ExecuteScalar(); 
    }
```

Or if you have a stored procedure on the database side, you could make it implicit within the stored procedures and just pass the paramaters that you need.

**Edit based on updated info,**

You could create temp tables on the database side with one query dividing each into separate years. You could do this against all the tables with one query and then drop the year from the rest of your queries if you point to the right tables.

**Additional Idea:**
I'm not too fluent with how this works but based on a little research, you could create filtered database snapshots for each year and update them on a daily basis on the server side. (msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175876.aspx) 
Then run queries against the snapshots ( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2007/06/06/querying-a-database-snapshot.aspx) and you wouldn't need to include the years as long as you know the snapshots.

Comment: let say that we have 30 tables 20 of theme have a 'Year' column, and the database has data for the last 5 years, and let say that we are intersting for one year data at a time, so we choose the year from a dropdown list, is there any way to do global projection so that way we can drop the '..and Year= ...' from our queries

Comment: Would you want to do a Join on those tables for your projection? If not, you could create temp tables on the database side with one query dividing each into separate years. You could do this against all the tables with one query and then drop the year from the rest of your queries if you point to the right tables

Comment: what i'm looking for is a way to have a view of the entire database that include only data for one year at a time

Comment: @anouar204 depends on which side you want to do the work....I've given you different options but depends on your situation. Which method sounds like it might suit you so I can elaborate

Comment: seems to be clause to what i'm looking for, if there is virtual snapshot support on sqlserver it will be great

Comment: the last option 'snapshot' seems to be clause to what i'm looking for, i'm going to make aditional research to see how it works, thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about just changing it to `... And Year = year(getdate())`

That would alway retrieve the current year. If that doesn't work then can you explain a little more about how the code is designed and builds SQL?

Comment: the column Year is just an example, we can say that we have a column wich is present in all  database tables; for example let say that we have a table in wich for 100 row we have Year = '2012' and for 200 row we have = '2011', my question is can we do a global projection for all the tables to filter only rows with Year = '2012' that way we dont have to put the and Year = '...' all the time we write a new query